# Don't get required field error while using save() method

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am doing a course, but it is quite old and there is no one to answer the question. I hope the information provided is enough.
Why don't i get an required field error, when use save() method without required schema fields given. I only describe two required fields: password and passwordConfirm, but no name and email, should't we get an required field error since we use save() method, which should run our schema validators.
I run this controller to update password:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwiev.png)
User schema:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yu2b.png)
Sending this body information via postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Zt3.png)

Answer (score 0):

runValidators command will only act on updated properties not others, thats why i got errors only from password validator, but no other required fields, because i didn't update other fields.